# Kendo numeric textbox in grid with Angular

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to use the numeric textbox from kendo, in Angular, inside a kendo grid. Binding the data with my angular object doesn't work. I tried to put an "editor" field in the columns object, or even to do it with a jQuery command (which I know is bad)like this:

```
$('.editable').kendoNumericTextBox()
```

but it never works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the *template* in the columns object, use the *editor* attribute:

```
{
    field: "fieldName",
    title: "Field Title",
    width: "90px",
    editor: numberEditor
}
```

The *numberEditor* is a function which you can implement as following:

```
function numberEditor(container, options) {
  $('<input name="' + options.field + '"/>')
  .appendTo(container)
  .kendoNumericTextBox({
    decimals: 0,   // Settings for the editor, e.g. no decimals
    step    : 1,   // Defines how the up/down arrows change the value
    min     : 0    // You can also define min/max values
});
```

}

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but when I do this I loose the binding on my angular object. My angular object is a bit complicated, and I can't access the value through options.field directly.
I found my solution by using schema and type="number"